# Google Glass - Code39 Scanner

Tags: android, java

I need a code39 Scanner for my glass application. I've tried with ZBar (version 0.2), but it doesn't work. As you can see the picture is upside down and the quality is very bad. ZBar only works with my smartphone. I've tried it with the code of lisah0: [ZBar source code](https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar/tree/master/android)

[image: ZBar camera]

I also tried Scandit but it doesn't support code39 in the community version.

Are there any alternatives?